# Will we be obligated to bring many chatats when the temple is rebuilt?

Tags: messiah, beis-hamikdash, sin, korban

When the Temple is rebuilt will we each have to bring chatats ("sin" offerings) as necessary based on different sins we have done (which would likely amount to quite a lot of korbanot for a lot of people) or is there some sort of process to "start over" and begin like new, bringing chatats only for new sins?

Is there perhaps some discussion of what happened with regards to this when the 2nd Temple was built?

Comment: Admittedly, there are tight specifications for when you are chayav a chatat, but still...

Comment: Relevant: "קרא והטה וכתב על פנקסו אני ישמעאל בן אלישע קריתי והטיתי נר בשבת לכשיבנה בהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמנה"  ([Shabbat 12b](http://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.12b.5?lang=he))

Comment: See my answer below, HOWEVER--In Ezra the pasuk says, "עזרא פרק ו
(יז) וְהַקְרִ֗בוּ לַחֲנֻכַּת֘ בֵּית־אֱלָהָ֣א דְנָה֒ תּוֹרִ֣ין מְאָ֔ה דִּכְרִ֣ין מָאתַ֔יִן אִמְּרִ֖ין אַרְבַּ֣ע מְאָ֑ה וּצְפִירֵ֨י עִזִּ֜ין לחטיא לְחַטָּאָ֤ה עַל־כָּל־יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ תְּרֵֽי־עֲשַׂ֔ר לְמִנְיָ֖ן שִׁבְטֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל " ---Ie they only brought 12 chatats, seemingly symbolic and not what they actually "owed"--do we say the same thing nowadays? How did that work (and how does it reconcile with my answer). They certainly didn't bring all the korbanot they owed, for just one year that would be around 1218.

Comment: Maybe that's just in addition to any personal chatats?

Answer (score 6):

As Scimonster mentioned the Gemara in Shabbos appears to address this. "קרא והטה וכתב על פנקסו אני ישמעאל בן אלישע קריתי והטיתי נר בשבת לכשיבנה בהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמנה" ([Shabbat 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.12b.5?lang=he))

Rabbi Yishmael would write down that he needs to bring a chatat when the Temple is rebuilt. This gemara seems to imply that in fact we will need to bring a chatat for each sin we commit. Additionally, there is a gemara in Yoma ([Yoma 80a](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.80a?lang=he)) and a Yerushalmi Chagiga (1:2) that require you to keep track of the size of forbidden foods you ate, seemingly for the purpose of knowing if you need to bring a korban when the temple is rebuilt.

The [Tiferet Shlomo](http://hebrewbooks.org/9747) (Moadim: Shabbos, *dibbur hamatchil* ואת מוסף) cites the gemara in Shabbos and even goes further and says that we will bring *every* obligatory sacrafice that we did not bring during exile, including daily-offerings (temidim).

There are others that share his view, as brought down in Daf al HaDaf (quoted below). One notable example appears to be the Magen Avrahom, who quotes the gemara in a halachic context in his commentary on the Shulchan Aruch (Siman 334 Seif 33).

However, the Lubavitcher Rebbe felt that we will not need to bring the korbanot we missed, and likewise sees no requirement to record the sins we have done (Shulchan Menachem page קכא, quoting Likutei Sichot חי״ח page 416).

See http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chatas-offering-in-future-for-the-accidental-sins-he-performed-during-galus/?hilite=chatas#ftn1 for a discussion of some of the above sources.

> דף על הדף שבת דף יב עמוד ב
>   כתב בתפארת שלמה מועדים עניני שבת (ד' כח ד"ה ואת מוסף וכו'): "לעתיד נשלים ונקריב את כל הקרבנות של חובה שחסרנו מהם בזמן הגלות, הנה אז נקריב כל התמידין והמוספין שהיינו מחוייבים בהם כל ימי הגלות, וכן כל קרבנות היחיד של חובה, וכמש"כ ר' ישמעאל (שבת י"ב, ב): לכשיבנה בהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמינה, וכמ"ש הכתוב 'ושלמתי לכם את השנים אשר אכל הארבה' וכו'. וזה שאנו אומרים כי את מוסף יום השבת הזה והחג הזה נקריב בבנין בהמ"ק במהרה בימינו אמן". עכ"ד.
>
> וראה גם בבני יששכר (מאמרי ר"ח - מאמר ב) שהביא בשם הרמ"ע מפאנו ז"ל, שלעתיד לבוא נצטרך להקריב את כל הקרבנות שחסרנו כל ימי גלותינו ע"ש, וביאר בזה הפסוקים שאומרים במוסף שבת ור"ח וכדברי התפארת שלמה הנ"ל ע"ש.
>
> כתב בספר מטעמי יעקב (פר' ויקרא): עיין שו"ת לב חיים להגאון ר' חיים פלאג'י זצ"ל או"ח (סימן כ"ט) דמסיק דהגם דכל הלומד פרשת עולה הוי כאילו הקריב קרבן עולה, אבל אחד דעבר עבירה עכשיו ולמד הפרשה, ואח"כ נבנה הבית המקדש בימיו, לא מיפטר מלהביא קרבן ממש בזה דלמד לפני כן. וכ"כ שו"ת חקרי לב או"ח סימן ב' והביא שם דבר פלא דמבואר בספר מקראי קדש (דס"ח ע"א) דלפי רבא אף בזמן המקדש יכול לקרוא בתורת חטאת ואשם ומיפטר בזה.
>
> ובשם הגאון מז"ה נר"ו הביא שם ראי' אלימתא משבת יב: דלא יתכן זה, דא"כ במעשה ברבי ישמעאל ברבי אלישע דקרא והטה, למה הי' צריך לכתוב על פנקסו אני ישמעאל בן אלישע קריתי והטיתי נר בשבת לכשיבנה ביהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמינה. ואם סגי בקריאה לחוד, למה לא קרא, אלא מכאן ראי' דאף בזמן שבהמ"ק חרב לא מועיל הקריאה.
>
> ובשם ספר קול יהודה כתב במעשה דר' ישמעאל בן אלישע דלא יועיל לעסוק בתורת חטאת, מפני דחלק הכהנים לא יכופר בקריאת הפרשה, אבל הקשה עליו הגאון מהר"ם דר' ישמעאל בן אלישע כהן הי' וכהן המקריב קרבן שלו עבודתו ועורו שלו, עיין שם.
>
> וכתב בשם ראש דוד דדחה הראי' דמצוה מן המובחר להקריב מבכורות צאנו ומחלביהן, ומדויק בזה הלשון שאמר יביא חטאת שמנה. ע"כ.
>
> ויש להביא כאן מש"כ בלקוטי יהודה (פר' תזריע ע' קד) בשם כ"ק אדמו"ר בעל האמרי אמת זצ"ל מגור שאמר בשם ספר א' בהא דאיתא בגמ' כאן דר"י כתב על פנקסו כשיבנה ביהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמינה. ולכאורה למה הוצרך לכך, הרי אמרינן דהעוסק וכו' כאילו הקריב, רק דהאכילה דכהנים אוכלים הרי היא חלק מהכפרה, וא"כ אפי' אי אמרינן כאילו הקריב, מ"מ הרי חסרה הכפרה דאכילת הכהנים, ולכן אמר שכאשר יבנה ביהמ"ק יביא חטאת שמינה, כדי למלא החלק של אכילת הכהנים עכ"ד שם ודפח"ח. (ויש להוסיף דבירושלמי (פ"א דשבת ה"ב) אי' דמעשה דר"י הנ"ל בלא התיבה: שמינה אלא חטאת לבד וי"ל).
>   בגמ': לכשיבנה ביהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמנה וכו'.
>
> העיר כ"ק אדמו"ר מהרמ"מ מלובאויטש זצ"ל: לכאורה אינו מובן, שהרי ברור שהי' אצל ר"י הענין ד"כל העוסק בתורת חטאת כאילו הקריב חטאת" (מנחות ק"י ע"א) וא"כ למה אמר ש"לכשיבנה ביהמ"ק אביא חטאת שמינה".
>
> אלא, שמזה מוכח שלימוד ההלכות אינו מגיע למעלה של קיום המצוה בפועל עכד"ק.

Comment: The information from http://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chatas-offering-in-future-for-the-accidental-sins-he-performed-during-galus/?hilite=chatas#ftn1 was left in an answer by someone else--but he did not summarize the link and his answer was since deleted, so I do not know who to credit. Very helpful link though! (So I felt I needed to add the info to my answer)