# Why did they not bring all the korbanot they owed in the time of Ezra?

Tags: messiah, beis-hamikdash, korban, ezra-nechemya

As discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81245/will-we-be-obligated-to-bring-many-chatats-when-the-temple-is-rebuilt/81251#81251) the gemara seems to suggest that when the temple is rebuilt we will to bring all the chatat offerings that we owe. According to those that hold that to be the case, how do they explain that they did *not* do so when the second temple was built?

Presumably they too should have brought the chatats they owe, but we see from the psukim in Ezra ("עזרא פרק ו (יז) וְהַקְרִ֗בוּ לַחֲנֻכַּת֘ בֵּית־אֱלָהָ֣א דְנָה֒ תּוֹרִ֣ין מְאָ֔ה דִּכְרִ֣ין מָאתַ֔יִן אִמְּרִ֖ין אַרְבַּ֣ע מְאָ֑ה וּצְפִירֵ֨י עִזִּ֜ין לחטיא לְחַטָּאָ֤ה עַל־כָּל־יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ תְּרֵֽי־עֲשַׂ֔ר לְמִנְיָ֖ן שִׁבְטֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל ") that they only brought one per tribe (as what seems to be some sort of symbolic gesture--exactly the type of gesture the other question asks if it is possible).

The question is even stronger for the opinion mentioned in the linked question that we owe *all* the korbanot we have missed, even temidim and musafim--in Ezra they only brought 700 korbanot, but the number of korbanot brought per year is about 1218...

Comment: The verse in Ezra isn't clear that they didn't bring all the Korbanot they owed. You are the one reading into it that those 12 are the symbolic gesture type. (Temidin and Musafim, ok I hear you.)

Comment: @DoubleAA How so? The way I read it it seems quite clear they didn't...You're saying these may not be the only korbanot they brought? You would then have to say that these specific korbanot had some special purpose worth mentioning explicitly.

Comment: Yes, what those Korbanot are is interesting, but there's no proof from the verses that over the next few weeks everyone didn't show up with what they owed.